# Google Analytics Report on Google Sheets- How to track goal completion of one goal and not all goals

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

Metrics: ga:goalCompletionsAll
Dimensions: ga:goalCompletionLocation
Filters: ga:goal==goal3completions

I get an error message on the above configuration. I'd like to track one particular goal from Google Analytics to Google Sheets. Can someone help?

Comment: Please share the error message you are receiving

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hi @etemple1. Sure. The Report Status says this- 1 report failed due to errors
•Conversion A: Invalid dimension or metric:

Comment: Thanks. It's still very difficult to help you with your issue due to lack of information provided, but the error is telling you that "Conversion A" is invalid so I would suggest trying to figure out what _valid_ metric or dimension should be put in it's place or why the google sheets API is finding it to begin with. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: Hi @etemple1. Thanks so much for the link. What I'm trying to do seems simple, but I don't get what's not working. I'm trying to track one goal and not all goals completed. I'll see what I can find in the guide you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Try this:*

Metrics: **ga:goal3Completions**

Dimensions: ga:goalCompletionLocation

Filters: (empty)